# replaceWith problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<br class = "xyzzy" id = "printed">datasetName</br>
```

Doing below.

```
$('#printed').replaceWith('<input class="form-control dataset-collection-on" id="create-dataset-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter dataset name"></input>')
```

results is this.

```
<input class="form-control dataset-collection-on" id="create-dataset-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter dataset name"></input>
datasetName
<br>
```

How do I get rid of datasetName and the branch tag..?

Comment: `<br>` is a void tag. A BR element can’t have children. `</br>` is invalid, and `datasetName` is not inside `<br>`. Maybe you meant to use a `<div>`?

Answer (score 3):

`<br>` is a line break and not to be used this way. Use a `div` instead.

```js
$('#printed').replaceWith('<input class="form-control dataset-collection-on" id="create-dataset-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter dataset name" />')
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="xyzzy" id="printed">datasetName</div>
```

Update: To insert text before the content, you can use [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```js
$('#printed').prepend('<input class="form-control dataset-collection-on" id="create-dataset-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter dataset name" /> <br>')
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="xyzzy" id="printed">datasetName</div>
```

Comment: `<input>` is a void element and has no closing `</input>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I am pretty new to this stuff ..  If I use a div how do I make it appear on new line..

Comment: what do you mean? like do you want the text and input box?

Comment: <div class = "xyzzy" id = "printed">datasetName</div>

I did above but I need datasetName to appear on a new line

Comment: have edited, check the second example. You can use `<br>` or wrap the `input` in a `div`